# Bhyve + IPv6 can't ping from guest to host until host ping guest

Tags: freebsd, ipv6

Both host/guest are using FreeBSD 11.1, I created the VM using [vm-byhbe](https://github.com/churchers/vm-bhyve).

This is host configuration in `/etc/rc.conf`

```
ifconfig_igb0_ipv6="inet6 2a01:4f8:150:84ec::1 prefixlen 64"
ipv6_activate_all_interfaces="YES"
ipv6_defaultrouter="fe80::1%igb0"
rtadvd_enable="YES"
```

In `/etc/rtadvd.conf`

```
igb0:\
        :addrs#1:addr="2a01:4f8:150:84ec::"\
        :prefixlen#64\
        :tc=ether\
        :rltime#0\
        :rdnss="2a01:4f8:150:84ec::1":
```

This is the [bhyve](http://bhyve.org/) guest `/etc/rc.conf`

```
ifconfig_vtnet0_ipv6="inet6 accept_rtadv"
ipv6_defaultrouter="fe80::1%vtnet0"
rtsold_enable="YES"
```

This is the output of `ifconfig bridge0` on the host:

```
bridge0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
    description: vm-public
    ether 02:e0:41:b7:a4:00
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
    groups: bridge
    id 00:00:00:00:00:00 priority 0 hellotime 2 fwddelay 15
    maxage 20 holdcnt 6 proto rstp maxaddr 2000 timeout 1200
    root id 00:00:00:00:00:00 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
    member: tap0 flags=143<LEARNING,DISCOVER,AUTOEDGE,AUTOPTP>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 7 priority 128 path cost 2000000
    member: igb0 flags=143<LEARNING,DISCOVER,AUTOEDGE,AUTOPTP>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 1 priority 128 path cost 2000000[/CODE]
```

The first problem I found is that after booting the VM, it takes a while to get an IP, in some cases I need to restart [rtadvd](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=rtadvd&sektion=8) and only then I can get an IP, the error I have in the logs is this one:

```
rtadvd[1871]: <getconfig> inet_pton failed for 2a01:4f8:150:84ec::
```

After the VM gets an IP,  I can ping other hosts for example [2001:4860:4860::8844](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using), but not the host itself,  therefore I can't resolve to any domain, this  is because  I am using [unbound](https://www.unbound.net/) on the host and is the DNS (/etc/resolve.conf)  that I have defined.

The only way I have found so far to fix this issue, is to ping from the Host to the IPv6 on the guest, after doing that everything works as expected.

Any ideas about what could it be wrong? for testing, I disabled [pf](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/firewalls-pf.html) (`pfctl -d`) but still not working.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to [fix this](https://nbari.com/post/bhyve-ipv6/), the main trick was to use only the bridge interface and enable `auto_linklocal` on it, something like this:

```
ifconfig_bridge0_ipv6="inet6 2a01:4f8:350:84ec::1 prefixlen 64 auto_linklocal"
rtadvd_enable="YES"
rtadvd_interfaces="bridge0"
```